# Find the length of a curve given by equations

Tags: calculus, curves

Find the length of a curve given by the equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $(x^2+y^2)^2=x^2-y^2$

I tried with polar parametrization and with spherical parametrization but I can't solve the definite integral that I come up with.

Comment: Include your work, including the definite integral, so that potential answerers know where to focus their attention.

Comment: (You should edit your question to include it, I mean, not post it in the comments.)

Comment: And also add what led to this specific integral... does not seem to be obvious for me.

Comment: I used the parametrization that @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura gave below

Answer (score 0):

$x(t) =r\cos t = \sqrt{\cos 2t}\cos t $

$y(t) =r\cos t = \sqrt{\cos 2t}\sin t $

$z(t) =\pm\sqrt{1-x^2 -y^2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos 2t}=\pm \sqrt{2}|\sin 2t|$

Comment: I think that the argument of $\sin$ in $z(t)$ is $t$, not $2t$. And then I can't solve the definite integral